# Cakephp 3 Transaction management on multiple model operation

Tags: php, cakephp, transactions, cakephp-3.0

I have a code block where multiple table database operation are done. I need to keep this code block in transaction. I am trying in following way in cakephp 3.

```
    $saveStatus = 1;
    $conn = ConnectionManager::get('default');
    $conn->begin();
    $tableArticles = TableRegistry::get('Articles');
    $tableUsers = TableRegistry::get('Users');
    $articlesEntity = $tableArticles->newEntities($categoriesArray);
    foreach ($articlesEntity as $entity) {          
        if(!$tableArticles->save($entity))
        {
            $saveStatus = 0;
        }
    }
    $usersEntity = $tableUsers->newEntities($usersArray);
    foreach ($usersEntity as $entity) {
        if(!$tableUsers->save($entity))
        {
            $saveStatus = 0;
        }
    }
    if($saveStatus ==1)
    {
        $conn->commit();

    }
    else
    {
        $conn->rollback();         

    }
```

But the transaction works for only one table.I want multiple table operation should be in transaction.

In cake 2, we do transaction using  begin() and commit() on each model data source like following.

```
   $mealOptionDataSource = $this->MealOptionFood->getDataSource ();
    $foodExtrasDataSource = $this->FoodExtras->getDataSource ();
    $complexOptionDataSource = $this->ComplexOptionFood->getDataSource ();

    $mealOptionDataSource->begin ();
    $foodExtrasDataSource->begin ();
    --- Code here---
    $mealOptionDataSource->commit ();
    $foodExtrasDataSource->commit ();
    $complexOptionDataSource->commit ();
```

I can't find a way how to do it in cake 3.

Thank in advances.

Comment: "_doesn't work_" is not a proper problem description! Please be more specific as to that what exatly happens/the problem is. Also please mention what you've tried so far to debug the problem.

Comment: It looks like this should work. Have you got SQL output to show what's happening? (I'm assuming that the tables are both in the same database, and that database is the one that's referenced by the "default" connection, and that the database engine in question supports transactions.)

Comment: Also, probably unrelated to your problem, but you might want to check out the "transactional" feature of Cake connections. It could simplify your code by wrapping your inserts in a function that you just return `false` from if you want to roll them back.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
http://api.cakephp.org/3.1/class-Cake.Database.Connection.html#_transactional

```html
$connection->transactional(function ($connection) {
  $connection->newQuery()->delete('users')->execute();
});
```

In the transactional function, the 'commit' or 'rollback' occurs automatically depending on the result of all queries inside.